# Issues with installing ORYX Editor developmentEnvironment

Tags: development-environment

I am working on a research project to develop some extensions to oryx development environment, however, I could not get oryx running on my machine (windows), I have followed the installation guide in this wiki http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/wiki/SetupDevelopmentEnvironment. However it seems there is something missing, when I try to access oryx from tomcat it says sources not available, I have updated the build.xml and build. properties with the needed information, but with no luck. I have one concern I am not sure if it is the cause of the problem which python, no matter how many times I install it and reinstall it, it does not appear among the languages in PostgreSQL installation wizard.

Appreciate if someone can help me with this.

thank you
Wadha